# Unable to select values from the select list

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest

my select list is getting populated via a service call but I cannot select any of the values from the select list.

```
AJS.$("#select2-actor").auiSelect2(
{
    placeholderOption: 'first',

    formatResult: function(actor) {
        return '<b>' + actor.text ;
    },
    data: function ()
    {
        var data = [];
        AJS.$.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'GET',
            url: AJS.params.baseURL+"/rest/leangearsrestresource/1.0/message/list/{actor}",
            async: false
            /*multiple: true*/
        }).done(function(result) {
            result = JSON.parse(result.value);
            for (var actor in result.actors) {
                data.push({
                    text : result.actors[actor]
                });
                //AJS.log(data)
            }
        });

        return {
            results: data
        };

    }
}
```

);

```
<div class="field-group">
    <label class="label">Actor Select</label>
    <input id="select2-actor" type="hidden" name="actor" style="width: 415px;" placeholder="Add an actor"/>

</div>
```

I am unable to figure out where I am going wrong.
Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alok15ee/64djszjf/9/)Link

Comment: Can you create https://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: @Ivan : How would I add my service code there?

Comment: You can mock it: https://www.mockable.io and use the URL of your mock service, like this one I have created few minutes ago: http://demo8836598.mockable.io/mock-it

Comment: Hi Ivan, thanks a lot providing the way.  Here is my jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/alok15ee/64djszjf/5/ and the mocked service link http://demo7511759.mockable.io/actor

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/alok15ee/64djszjf/9/

Comment: Source of the issue is here: `<li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-unselectable">` - change the class name to `select2-result-selectable` and it starts working. But I am not able to figure out who sets this class name, as it resets to `select2-result-unselectable` right after the click.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ivan , after you suggested the problem I goggled it out and found out I was missing id attribute for result data. Select2 plugins wants an id field on data and if it is not there, it makes option "unselectable". http://jsfiddle.net/alok15ee/64djszjf/15/

Comment: I figured out the same thing, but few minutes late :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/64djszjf/14/

If you take a look at the source `js` file: https://aui-cdn.atlassian.com/aui-adg/5.8.13/js/aui-experimental.js, there are few lines that sets `unselectable` class:

```
populateResults: function(container, results, query) {
var populate, id=this.opts.id;

populate=function(results, container, depth) {

    var i, l, result, selectable, disabled, compound, node, label, innerContainer, formatted;

    results = opts.sortResults(results, container, query);

    for (i = 0, l = results.length; i < l; i = i + 1) {

        result=results[i];

        disabled = (result.disabled === true);
        selectable = (!disabled) && (id(result) !== undefined);

        compound=result.children && result.children.length > 0;

        node=$("<li></li>");
        node.addClass("select2-results-dept-"+depth);
        node.addClass("select2-result");
        node.addClass(selectable ? "select2-result-selectable" : "select2-result-unselectable");
```

which indicates that this `js` file requires `id` attribute of the object passed in.

My fix was to simply add `id` field to your javascript:

```
    for (var actor in result.actors) {

    data.push({
        text : result.actors[actor],
        id: "1"

    });
    AJS.log(data)
}
```

This also indicates that you might want to change your REST service to return ids, along with the names of Actors.